# unable to get test coverage of a method inside componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm testing a reactjs class component with enzyme and I can't seem to target this one function call

ClassComponentFile.jsx

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, { layout: prevLayout }) {
  const { setData, interaction } = this.props;

console.log('prevProp', prevProps.interation.data.requestSuccessful)
console.log('current Value',this.props.interation.data.requestSuccessful)


  if (prevProps.interaction.data.responseSuccessful
    !== interaction.data.responseSuccessful) {
     console.log('here');
    this.proceedToNextModuleClick();  <-- This Function Call
  }
}
```

TestingFile

```
const PROPS = {
...
  interaction: {
    data: {},
  },
...
};

  it('should call invoke proceedToNextModuleClick', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ServicingPortalLayoutController {...PROPS} />);

    const initialLayout = getInitialLayout({
      proceedToNextModuleClick: jest.fn(),
    }); 

    wrapper.setState({ layout: initialLayout });
    const proceedMock = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'proceedToNextModuleClick');

    const newProps = PROPS;
    newProps.interaction.data = { responseSuccessful: true };
    wrapper.setProps(newProps);

    expect(proceedMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

The "here" console.log never gets invoked. The first time component did update gets invoked prevProps and current Value are both false and then the next time it gets invoked the values are both true, which means it never satisfies the condition to reach the method.

I've tried this as well
    `wrapper.instance().componentDidUpdate(PROPS, initialLayout);` No luck with that either.

Is there something I'm missing about setProps? or any explanation for this behavior of both the previous and current props being the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you do `const newProps = PROPS;` you don't copy the object but use the same reference. You change some stuff inside, but equality checks are shallow, so the component is not updated because it sees the same props object as before.

Try `const newProps = {...PROPS};` to check if that is the issue.